# What is difference between reward points and price in reward points in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

In opencart administrator,

When we add reward points through the administrator,

So I understand that what is the use of textbox value in front of label 'points'.

but what is the use of text box marked in red?

And where it is applicable on website?
Refer screenshot.

Thanks!!![image]

Answer (score 0):

In opencart you can buy product with reward points as well and customer earns reward points when he buys product which have reward points.

In this case if you wish to buy this product with reward point, you must have at least `1000` points,

In each purchase customer (Default group) gets `200` points for buying this product.

[image]

```
// checkout/cart
```

Here i have `10200` reward points, i need only `1000` reward points to buy this product and in total you can see `$0.00`